# Retain index column in exported csv file from pgAdmin4

Tags: sql, postgresql, export

I have a simple postgresql table in pgAdmin4 with 3 columns (a,b,c) and an index column that I want to export to csv:

[image]

I tried using pgAdmin4's Import/Export functionality but the exported csv used column "a" as the index:

[image]

How do I export it as is above, such that the index column is retained and separate from the 3 columns (a, b, c), without having to explicitly create an "index" column in pgAdmin4 prior to the export?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'e confused about the meaning of this sequential numeration on the left side of your first image. It is **not** an index. It is just a sort of *visual help* for letting you know which row your're seeing, and it does not get exported. Perhaps [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) is what you're looking for:

Data Sample

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mynewc (a int, b int, c int);
INSERT INTO mynewc VALUES (1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9);
```

Exporting using [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html)

```
COPY (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS index,* FROM mynewc
) TO STDOUT CSV HEADER; 

index,a,b,c
1,1,4,7
2,2,5,8
3,3,6,9
```

If you're wondering how you get a file out of it, change the `STDOUT` by a path, e.g. `'/home/jason/mynewc.csv'`. Keep in mind that the OS user `postgres` needs write access to the given path.